# Problem Condition and Algorithm Stability

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods, error-propagation

Consider 2 mathematical problems:

$$
f_1(x) = a - x \\
f_2(x) = e^x -1
$$

The condition number for a function is defined as follows:

$$
k(f) = \left| x \cdot \frac{f'}{f} \right|
$$

Lets analyze conditioning first:

$$
k(f_1) = \frac{x}{x - a},
$$

which means that $f_1$ is **ill-conditioned** near $x = a$;

$$
k(f_2) = \frac{x \cdot e^x}{e^x - 1},
$$

which is undefined near $x = 0$, so lets use L'Hospital:

$$
k(f_2) = \frac{e^x + x \cdot e^x}{e^x},
$$

which means that $f_2$ is **well-conditioned** everywhere (including $x = 0$ proximity).

Now lets analyze stability of these 2 algorithms (if we were to implement them on the computer directly):

$$
\frac{(a - x) \cdot (1 + \epsilon_1) - (a - x)}{a - x} = \epsilon_1,
$$

where $\epsilon_1 \leq \epsilon_m$, and which means that no (numerical) amplification of errors occurs and the algorithm is **stable**;

$$
\frac{(e^x \cdot (1 + \epsilon_1) - 1) \cdot (1 + \epsilon_2) - (e^x - 1)}{e^x - 1} \approx \{\epsilon_1 \cdot \epsilon_2 \to 0\} \approx \frac{e^x \cdot \epsilon_1 + (e^x - 1) \cdot \epsilon_2}{e^x - 1} = \epsilon_2 + \epsilon_1 \cdot \frac{e^x}{e^x - 1},
$$

where $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2 \leq \epsilon_m$, and which means that the algorithm is **unstable** near $x = 0$.

Although everything is allright from the mathematical point of view, i.e. if we obey the formulas and raw theory when obtaining such results, but I begin to doubt in the validity of these results when I try add some logic and reasoning behind it.

First of all, as far as I understand, when we study conditioning of the mathematical problem we think of it in **exact arithmetics** (i.e. we do not think about computers, rounding, floating-point arithmetic, and etc.). Therefore, if I forget for a moment about the result obtained by analyzing $k(f_1)$ and just look on the simple mathematical problem $f_1(x) = a - x$, then I merely don't see how on earth it could be **ill-conditioned** near $x = a$. What is the physical reasoning behind it? What kind of bad thing can happen in **exact arithmetic** near $x = a$?

My curriculum pointed out **cancellation error** as an explanation. What kind of **cancellation error**? From my point of view, there is no such thing as **cancellation error** in **exact arithmetic**...

So, my reason against it would be straightforward, since **ill-condition** implies that **the output changes drastically when the input changes slightly**, then $f_1$ is clearly linear (moreover with coefficient $1$) and any slight changes of $x$ (regardless of whether near $a$ or not) will always result in the **quantitatively equal** change of $y = f_1(x)$ (i.e. $\Delta x \equiv \Delta y$). Therefore, I insist that $f_1$ can in no way be **ill-conditioned** neither at $x = a$ nor anywhere else.

Are there any flaws in my reasoning? Please, clarify this for me as I'm actually stuck on it.

Secondly, why it turns out that $f_2$ is **well-conditioned** while it looks the same as $f_1$? I mean if I follow the same logic as for $f_1$ (i.e. that it's **ill-conditioned** at $x = a$ because of **cancellation** as my curriculum states), then I could say the same here - **ill-conditioned** at $x = 0$, just by looking on the definition of $f_2$! However, mathematics show us that it's not true, but rather that the direct implementation of $f_2$ evaluation on computer would result in **unstable** algorithm. Due to what? I guess now it's **cancellation error** because we are in the floating-point world now. But why?

And still the question is why these two seemingly similar problems are actually so different? I'd really appreciate an exhaustive breakdown of these problems as I feel that I'm missing something very basic and it might prevent my understanding of more challenging phenomena.

Comment: Your application of your definition of condition number to $f_1$ and $f_2$ are incorrect. You are using $f'$ over $f$.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I messed up the formula, I'll edit it. $f'$ should be in the numerator of course. But calculations of condition numbers of both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are still fine.